# How to get regex Root domain?

Tags: regex

I'm working in an old, outdated templating-language called nVelocity. In it, you can do regex replaces, but you can only target the entire string.

I wish to replace the domain. I've come up with this:

```
#set ($alternateHost = $Regex.Replace($PageMeta.CanonicalUrl, ':\/\/(.[^/:]+)', 'www.newdomain.com'))
```

this would output

```
httpwww.newdomain.com
```

It replaces :// before the domain aswell. I don't want that. How can I do a regex that only targets the domain. I don't need support for usernames or ports, but I do need to support parameters, protocol and paths. (hashes is a nice to have)

Comment: put `://` in the replacement string!